# change selected to true angularjs

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I want to change at my api, `selected: true` when i click on current Inventory.

Can i do something like this ?

```
app.controller('InventoryDetailCtrl', function($scope, Inventory, Assigned, Tags, Restangular, currentInventory) {
$scope.inventories = new Inventory().query().$object;

$scope.selected = function(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
        if($scope.inventories[i].id == id){
            console.log(id);
            var selectedInventory = Restangular.copy($scope.currentInventory);
            selectedInventory.customPUT({selected: True });
        } 
    }
};

});
```

Here i got my states, where i get my current Inventory

```
.state('inventory.detailview',{
url:'/detailview',
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'InventoryDetailCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'inventory/detail.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
    currentInventory: function($stateParams, Inventory){
        return new Inventory().get($stateParams.id).$object;
        }
```

and in my template i do like this

```
<div ng-repeat="inventory in inventories">
    <a href="" ng-click="selected(inventory.id)">{{inventory.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
    $scope.selected = function(id) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
            if($scope.inventories[i].id == id){
                console.log(id);
                var selectedInventory = Restangular.copy($scope.inventories[i]);
                selectedInventory.customPUT({checked : true});                  
            } 
        }
    };
```